# Can't find bootstrap.css in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the 'bootstrap-sass' gem and can't find the .css file in my directory. It's currently working as my css tags/classes/etc all still work, I just don't know where the file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it just puts the assest with all your other gemfiles.  If you are using RVM trying looking here where you replace the user and version with yours.

/Users/kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.3.1/vendor/assets

The actual files are not included in your project, but you have access to them.  Everything is describe on the github README page.

Comment: argh, then how are you supposed to change the nav bar color ?